# TypeScript - why array .includes() expects searchElement to be "never" type?

Tags: typescript

I have object where every field is array of strings. I also have string variable that can have only values based on that arrays values in object.

Now I want to check to which array (which object field) this string belongs to. I'm doing this by simply using `includes()` and code works fine, but for some reason TS is complaining. Even that certain array can have certain values, it excepts from me "never" instead. I simplified code to just show TS issue.

```
const demo = {
  a: ['value1', 'value2'],
  b: ['value3'],
} as const

let demoValue: typeof demo[keyof typeof demo][number]  // possible "value1" "value2" "value3"
demoValue = 'value3' // some user interaction

const test = (parent: keyof typeof demo, value: typeof demoValue) => {
  console.log(demo[parent].includes(value)) // "type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'"
}

test('a', 'value2') // ok
test('WRONG', 'value2') // there is TS error, so ok
test('a', 'WRONG') // there is TS error, so ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwLYhgXhgbwFAxgQwC4YBtAcgDd8AbAVwQEYyAaGSm%20gJjIF1ncYAI2LkqdBAGZe-AL4EIMUJCjZs1BLEQoAahwTEoATwAOCEADN4yECQDWCQxZhHTTrSB4kwtJIIQAnHjwAemCYYxAICABLQXUYACIxegYExOSETjSkvQkE7HddcXQ2DKkYUJgIECQEGFoIAJhosCgA-GAoaPBVJWhnBH6MAApjfH8EVuJ7R0sXM0t3VgyDEwWrHT0ASnQAPiwBPpB1ADpqEABzYfcSMYnWnhOW4DpECGGMrZ3KhPm2aH8LQuZGaCjAIFg%20Ci0QuYHwcTqUFQfzIYAQFACZHyMlUbWgwzI%20BYpT03G%20YRAtmweKgBIA6gAlADyADkAOLE9jiMkVMJQAAWATq0QUAX8IH8rGqMEp1MGtMJnMZrI55OcgomoJgYolUtQsuwQA)

I can "fix" that by making `includes(value as never)` but I feel like this is not real fix but more workaround for wrong types...

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255) - `.includes` has a very (arguably too) strict type definition, and funky-looking workarounds are the only way to get past it, so don't feel bad

Comment: I knew I had seen this before, but I couldn't remember where. Thanks for finding that issue link, CertainPerformance.

Comment: to expand on others, `includes` only lets you check an array for values that might be in the array. you're trying to check if a value is in array type `['value1', 'value2'] | ['value3']` and the union of those two arrays is type `never` since they have no common values. you're essentially using `includes` to check which array you have, rather than using it to check if a given value is in an array. I agree this is a shortcoming, but that's why it's happening.  if you were, for instance, to declare `a` and `b` as type `string[]` then it would work fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a type assertion, but in this case there is a slightly safer option. If you declare a `wideList` that is an array of the union of all possible values, you can assign the union of lists to that without using `as`.

```
const test = (parent: keyof typeof demo, value: typeof demoValue) => {
  const wideList: readonly (typeof demoValue)[] = demo[parent];

  console.log(wideList.includes(value));
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwLYhgXhgbwFAxgQwC4YBtAcgDd8AbAVwQEYyAaGSm+gJjIF1ncYAI2LkqdBAGZe-AL4EIMUJCjZs1BLEQoAahwTEoATwAOCEADN4yECQDWCQxZhHTTrSB4kwtJIIQAnHjwAemCYYxAICABLQXUYACIxegYExOSETjSkvQkE7HddcXQ2DKkYUJgIECQEGFoIAJhosCgA-GAoaPBVJWhnBH6MAApjfH8EVuJ7R0sXM0t3VgyDEwWrHT0ASnQAPiwBPtgAd2jEABlo6GIJ-DhwakMYYfm3ayL6LZIgjHcSMYmrR4AG5VHg+iB1AA6aggADmw1OFyuUChLWAdEQEGGGS2W1BMlUbWgwzI+BYpT03B2lRAtmwxKgpIA6gAlADyADkAOIU9jiakVMJQAAWATqVxgAX8IH8rGqMDpDMGTLJfLZXN5NOFYomzQU0tl8tQSuwQA)

Update: Just thought of another solution, you could define a functional `includes` (rather than OO), which is better able to deal with unions of lists:

```
const includes = <T>(arr: readonly T[], x: T): boolean => arr.includes(x)

const test = (parent: keyof typeof demo, value: typeof demoValue) => {
  console.log(includes(demo[parent], value))
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwLYhgXhgbwFAxgQwC4YBtAcgDd8AbAVwQEYyAaGSm+gJjIF1ncYAI2LkqdBAGZe-AL4EIMUJCjZs1BLEQoAahwTEoATwAOCEADN4yECQDWCQxZhHTTrSB4kwtJIIQAnHjwAemCYYxAICABLQXUYACIxegYExOSETjSkvQkE7HddcXQ2DKkYUJgIECQEGFoIAJhosCgA-GAoaPBVJWhmsGA6RAUMAB4AFQA+AAp8f39ifwR8OHBqQxgJkj4YAA9iCYBKYkEQEHV8MHQpggWAOhah2hGZvaPe8H62-owZ43mCFaxHsjksLjMlncrAyBhMkKsOj0RxuWAEfQuCHu1BAAHMZk9hggIDN3CQActWrsMkcjgBubAyVQ-KAzMj4FilPTcFGVEC2bAstkAdQASgB5AByAHFOexxDyKmEoAALAJ1aIKAL+ED+VjVGD8wXE1nsuViqWy3nKtXLZpaha6-WoI3YIA)

Comment: Thanks! I was using `string[] | number[]` and facing the same error, changing to `(string | number)[]` solved my problem